# Kafka Best Way to Filter Messages

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

One application (producer) is publishing messages and these messages are being consumed by another application (with multiple consumers). Producer sends data with field country and we will have multiple consumers in our application, each consumer will subscribe to specific country.

From what I have been reading so far, we can have 2 approaches to filter message:

1. Filter data on consumer side: Producer can add country in message
   header. Consumer will receive all data and filter country it needs by checking
   from message header. Not sure if we can/should have multiple Consumers with different filters on different countries? Or just one Consumer that filters out the list of countries and we do aggregation by countries on our own?
2. One topic with separate partition for separate
   country: We will have a custom partitioner on Producer so it can send
   message to a specific partition. Consumers will be directed to the
   right partition for consuming country specific message.

My question is should we choose option 1 or 2? We are expecting to receive hundreds of messages every few seconds.

Comment: Are you developing a stateful application where all the messages from a given country should always be processed by the same service so they always have access to the whole state?

Comment: @GerardGarcia yes, all messages will be processed by the same service. However, each country will have different processing logics

Comment: Your question is more about Topic Partition design than about "filtering". If you shove all data into one topic, you have no choice but to filter. But then you may have "hanging" processes that are waiting for all events of a "busy country"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience typically the first approach is used.

The second option is problematic. What if you add a new country? You will need to add a partition to the topic, which is possible but not straightforward. You will also need to change the logic on the producer and conusmer side. If consumers are just subscribed to the topic, then in case of failure partitions will be automatically assigned to the alive consumers inside the consumer group. In your case you will need to handle the failures with the programming logic.

Another approach is to have a topic per country.

One more approach is to publish all the data into one topic and then distribute data to other topics(each per consumer) with Kafka Streams application. If the requirements change then you change the implementation of Kafka Streams app.

Comment: Thanks! With the first approach, is it possible to have multiple consumers filtered by a specific country each in an application?

Comment: You need to program this logic. Read everything and then forward to the correct service depending on the country.

Comment: Do you mean one or multiple consumers? One consumer means we need to check the country from header then decide which service to forward. Multiple consumers means we filter by a country per consumer

Comment: In Kafka clients consumers cooperate within the consumer group to process data in parallel. Each partition is assigned only to one consumer. In your case all consumers may have the same logic: read data->analyze country->forward to specific service. If you need ordering between messages from the same country then use country as a key.